# SharedObject between Air and Flex Web application

Tags: apache-flex, air, shared-objects

I have an Air application that runs an embedded web flex application (This is done in that way because remoteObject calling is faster than webService calling). The problem is that I need to have a sharedObject between air and web embedded application.

Is this possible in flex?

Answer (score 2):

SharedObjects of AIR applications are stored in a different directory than SharedObjects of web applications. Also, every AIR application and web domain has its own directory for SharedObjects. So you can't read SharedObjects from other apps directly.

You could try to read and parse the `.sol` files of your web application from your AIR app using the file system API but this won't be trivial.

Comment: Thank you. this clarify me a lot. I'm getting another approach